# Is there a way to rebuild every index in every schema through stored procedure / plsql?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing, plsql

Can't seem to figure a stored procedure that will rebuild every index online in every schema in the database. I'm just not thinking very straight on this.

```
create or replace procedure rebuild_indexes(
    p_owner in varchar2,
    p_table_name in varchar2
) as
begin
    for indexes_to_rebuild in
    (
        select index_name
        from all_indexes
        where owner = p_owner
        and table_name = p_table_name
    ) loop
        execute immediate 'alter index '||p_owner||'.'
            ||indexes_to_rebuild.index_name||' rebuild online';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Given that rebuilding indexes usually achieves nothing in the long run except burning crunch, what is your thinking behind writing this procedure?

Comment: @APC Frequent changes to tables in the database require index rebuilds, it is a routine to help tune performance. And routines often get automated.

Comment: The procedure is fine, however it will not catch partitioned indexes, i.e. it will fail on them.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Makes sense, so you're saying I should just add a line to output any errors? The procedure above only gave me a compilation error message.

Comment: Routinely rebuilding all the indexes in a schema will not "tune performance". There is a specific issue with partitioned indexes after partition maintenance, but as Wernfried points out, your procedure does not handle partitioned indexes anyway.

Comment: *"The procedure above only gave me a compilation error message. "* What message? Your procedure compiles and runs for me.

Comment: "Frequent changes to tables in the database require index rebuilds, it is a routine to help tune performance"  No, frequent changes do _not_ require index rebuilds. That is an old chestnut that has been repeatedly debunked by some of the best oracle performance experts in the world.  And while it may be "routine" in your shop, that is far from universal.

Comment: @EdStevens I'm no expert, I've only worked professionally as an Oracle DBA for 3 years now with versions 12c and prior. I've learned off of the Senior DBAs that I work alongside of. Merely having Indexes will not keep the system at high performance. With the increase in the data in the underlying table, the indexes keep fragmenting. Index rebuild exists to recreate the indexes and all underlying stats. It is very visible through monitoring. So I felt it is a good maintenance practice to reindex or defrag the regularly. I would be please if you could share sources regarding your point.

Comment: @Phillip Since this question seems to be based on the code in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11334147/409172), I modified my answer to include more information about how constantly rebuilding indexes is often a bad idea. But there are always exceptions, and I know that many people have strong feelings about this topic. It's often easier to just nod my head and rebuild the index than it is to argue about it.

Comment: @Phillip - Do you trust Tom Kyte? "99.9% of all reorgs, rebuilds, etc are a total and utter waste of time and energy" (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3035290021641).  How about Richad Niemiec? "The need for repeated reorganizations should be a thing of the past for most DBAs " https://logicalread.com/oracle-11g-fragmentation-myths-realities-mc02/#.X9N3srNMHIU)  Or Richard Foote? Just google 'oracle index rebuild myth'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a procedure like this by slightly modifying the parameters and query against ALL_INDEXES

```sql
DECLARE
    PROCEDURE rebuild_indexes (p_owner        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                               p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
    AS
    BEGIN
        FOR indexes_to_rebuild
            IN (SELECT owner, index_name
                  FROM all_indexes
                 WHERE owner = NVL (p_owner, owner) AND table_name = NVL (p_table_name, table_name))
        LOOP
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'alter index '
                                 || indexes_to_rebuild.owner
                                 || '.'
                                 || indexes_to_rebuild.index_name
                                 || ' rebuild online';
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS
                THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                           'Failed to rebuild index '
                        || indexes_to_rebuild.owner
                        || '.'
                        || indexes_to_rebuild.index_name
                        || ': '
                        || SQLERRM);
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END;
BEGIN
    --Rebuild all indexes on a table
    rebuild_indexes (p_owner => 'APEX_190200', p_table_name => 'WWV_FLOWS');
    --Rebuild all indexes in a schema
    rebuild_indexes (p_owner => 'APEX_190200', p_table_name => NULL);
    --Rebuild all indexes
    rebuild_indexes (p_owner => NULL, p_table_name => NULL);
END;
/
```

Comment: This seemed to work successfully, thanks!!